# Why view state is not available for VF page with JQuery Plugins?

Tags: visualforce, viewstate

Whenever i use JQuery Plugin in VF page, view state disappears. Is there any alternate way to check view state while using Plugins. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by disappear? don't you see view state tab from developer tool bar ?

Comment: just now i tried but view state tab is visible for me

Comment: @Himanshu yes as soon as save after using jquery view state disappears.

Comment: @Ratan Are you sure you used Jquery Plugin!

Comment: Yes. let me show you a screenshot

Comment: This is the  screenshot http://postimg.org/image/wyzz5hhr9/. you can see the code. I am using jquery and view state tab is visible

Comment: venky can you update this question with your screenshot

Comment: @Ratan Thanks for your time, something went wrong & now it is clear.

Comment: ok no problem @Venky. Pls update your question with a screenshot